# Text hidden behind background image HTML

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML code: http://ideone.com/ExjCnv

```css
@import url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
/* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the
   default style applied by Bootstrap */
body {
  background: url(img/dark.png); !important;
  position:relative; z-index:-1;
}
#logo {
  text-indent: 500px;
  z-index:9999;
  position:relative;
}
#links { padding-top: 0.7cm }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" id="logo">
      <h2>Audhgjhg</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" align="right" id="links">
      <a href="C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Code\I\tp.html">Read</a>
      <a href="#">Write</a>
      <a href="#">Play</a>
      <a href="#">Help</a>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#666633">
    <h1 align="center">Read books</h1>
    <h4 align="center">Enter a bookname:</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
    </div>  
  </div>                    
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The text on line 26: `<h2>Audhgjhg</h2>` is not displayed in the browser. I tried setting the z-index of the text and the background but it's still hidden. Please help.

Comment: did you play around with this in Developer Tools? you're setting z-index to the parent of your `<h2>` tag - are you sure that the tag itself has a correct z-index and other properties?

Comment: You have unnecessary `;` after `background: url(img/dark.png)`

Comment: @Alejalapeno Yes the logo is smaller than 500px. I am new to web development, so can you please explain a little.

Comment: If this is all of your code then I have to ask... Is dark.png really dark and you just aren't seeing the text because it's black? What if you add `#logo { color: white; }`?

Comment: @Alejalapeno That works. But the logo is not completely dark. It's this http://subtlepatterns.com/dark-embroidery/ Without the color property, the text is hidden.

Comment: Bootstrap gives the text `color: #333`. When I eyedrop that background image the main dark color is `#333`. You're simply placing same colored text over the background.

Comment: @Alejalapeno Thanks for your help. BTW your portfolia website looks great. Did you use anything else apart from Bootstrap for the UI?

Comment: I posted an answer for you to accept incase anyone else views the question. Also, thanks. skrollr.js and smoothState.js for functionality on my site, but no frameworks all from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background `dark.png` used was http://subtlepatterns.com/dark-embroidery/ which consists mainly of the dark grey color `#333`. Bootstrap was assigning `#333` as the text color and making the text appear to not show while it matched the background.

Answer (score -1):

excuse me ... first from this

```
    <style type="text/css">
   body { background: url(img/dark.png); !important; position:relative; z-index:-1; } /* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */
</style>
<style>   
   #logo { text-indent: 500px; z-index:9999; position:relative;}
</style>
<style>   
   #links {padding-top: 0.7cm}
</style>
```

do this

```
<style type="text/css">
    //edited
   body { background: url(img/dark.png); !important; position:relative; z-index:-1; } /* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */
   #logo { text-indent: 500px; z-index:9999; position:relative;}
   #links {padding-top: 0.7cm}
</style>
```

also i think that it is background: `url(img/dark.png) !important;` not `background: url(img/dark.png); !important;`

change all that it should be fine. it works for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>A</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
       body { background: url(http://images.hngn.com/data/images/full/47684/selena-gomez.jpg?w=650); !important; position:relative; z-index:-1; } /* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */
       #logo { text-indent: 500px; z-index:9999; position:relative;}
       #links {padding-top: 0.7cm}
     </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8" id="logo">
                    <h2>Audhgjhg</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" align="right" id="links">
                    <a href="C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Code\I\tp.html">Read</a>
                    <a href="#">Write</a>
                    <a href="#">Play</a>
                    <a href="#">Help</a>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#666633">
                <h1 align="center">Read books</h1>
                <h4 align="center">Enter a bookname:</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="usr"></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
                </div>  
            </div>                    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code works fine when the image is large but not when it's small.

Comment: http://codepen.io/LEGGATH/pen/BoWqQX?editors=100

it works for me ... i realy dont know what do you need. text is visible, and the image if it is small is repeated. Maybe it is to the picture , maybe the position of the text is in place of picture with the same color.